# Deducing template member function in class template

Tags: c++, templates

Why can't `T` be deduced from `fn`'s signature in the following example?

```
template<int I>
struct Class {
    template<typename T>
    Class &operator <<( void (*)(const Class<I> &, const T &) ) { return *this; }
};

struct Ot { };

template<int I>
void fn(const Class<I> &, const Ot &) { }

int main() {
    Class<1>() << fn;
}
```

Where in contrast, the following example without the `operator<<` being a regular member is legal:

```
template<int I>
struct Class {
    Class &operator <<( void (*)(const Class<I> &) ) { return *this; }
};

struct Ot { };

template<int I>
void fn(const Class<I> &) { }

int main() {
    Class<1>() << fn;
}
```

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I want to ask why

Comment: Mainly for my understanding of template deduction rules :-} I've been straying around this with a couple of questions in the last few days.

Comment: Regarding your edit, the basic idea is that a template function can't help the compiler disambiguate `fn` because it'd have to simultaneously guess what the template parameters of both `fn` and `operator<<` should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it comes down to is that the template parameters for a function template can be either explicitly specified or they can be deduced from the arguments passed to the function.

In your example, the compiler can't determine the template parameter for `fn` because there are no arguments being passed to it in the call to `Class<1>::operator<<()`. Therefore, you must explicitly specify it:`fn<1>` (or whatever you want it to be). Once you've done this, and `fn`'s type is unambiguous, the compiler can deduce the type of `T` from `Class<1>::operator()`'s second parameter type (i.e. fn<1>).

In other words, the type of `fn` isn't clear. You could be passing fn<2> to Class<1>::operator<<(). Consider this code:

```
Class<1> << fn<2>;   // fn<2> is not fn<1>
Class<1> << fn<1>;   // OK too, of course
Class<1> << fn;      // error! fn<?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because just like you're using `Class<1>` instead of `Class`, you have to provide the template parameter to the function template `fn` as well:

```
Class<1>() << fn<1>;
```

Also, you might want to return a reference from your `operator <<`:

```
template<typename T>
Class & operator <<( void (*)(const Class<I> &, const T &) ) { return *this; }
      ^
```

Comment: Fixed the reference return, absolutely true.

Comment: This does not answer the question which was *why* the template parameter `T` cannot be deduced, not *that* it cannot be deduced.